# How to deal with skewness in IV

Tags: regression, data-transformation, skewness

I'm Building a logistic regression model and one of my independent variables is very skewed at zero. How do you suggest that i deal with this situation?

Comment: Why do you think that this is a problem? Is the independent variable in question continuous or categorical?

Comment: some sample data/ reproducible example would help

Comment: It is continuous. 25% of the values are zero. I want to know the best practice od deal with it. Should create a dummy variable indicating zero and non-zero and add it to the model along with the original variable

Comment: If i take a log transformation of the data the data looks normally dist wxcept for the spike at 0. Btw I'm taking log(1+x)

Comment: Why would you care whether the log of (1+x) looks normal?

Comment: Plot the response against the predictor in question as  a start. Normality is an unattainable ideal because **a spike can only map to another spike**. Transforming the data *might* possibly help given marked outliers or obvious nonlinearity but there is no requirement for predictors to be normally distributed. (If there were, then using indicator (dummy) variables as predictors would have to be banned....)

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is to not transform independent variables unless there is a substantive reason for doing so, such as aiding interpretation, dealing with known non-linearity or heteroscedasticity.

There is no distributional requirement or condition for independent variables, so, often, there is no need to do so.